# Collision of sprites that vary in size in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am trying to code something similar to the game flappy bird. In my program, I want to be able to check whether the bird is in contact with the pipe, and if so, the game should end. I have a pipe class and a bird class, and I have two instances of the pipe class:

```
bird = bird(125,185)
pipe1 = pipe(300, 255)
pipe2 = pipe(520, 255)
```

In my pipe class I have these two methods relating to the height and position of the pipe:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.bottom = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("pipe.png"), (52,145))
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 52
    self.height = 145

def resize(self): # The height of the pipe will vary randomly
    self.height = random.randint(100,150)
    self.bottom = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("pipe.png"), (52,self.height))
    self.y = 400 - self.height

def draw(self, win):
    if self.x > -52:
        self.x -= 5 # Pipe will move to the left of the screen
    else:
        self.x = 400
        self.resize()
    win.blit(self.bottom, (self.x,self.y))
    self.top = pygame.transform.rotate(self.bottom, 180) # There is a bottom pipe and a top pipe
    win.blit(self.top, (self.x,0))
```

As you can see, for each instance of the pipe class, two pipes are drawn on the screen. One at the top of the screen and one opposite it at the bottom. The two pipes then both move across the screen.

This is some of the code from the bird class:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.bird1 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("bird1.png"), (34,24))
    self.bird2 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("bird2.png"), (34,24))
    self.bird3 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("bird3.png"), (34,24))
    self.birdpics = [self.bird1, self.bird2, self.bird3]
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 34
    self.height = 24
    self.moveCount = 0
    self.jumpCount = 7
    self.isJump = False
    self.image = self.birdpics[self.moveCount]

def draw(self, win):
    self.moveCount += 1
    if self.moveCount >= len(self.birdpics):
        self.moveCount = 0
    self.image = self.birdpics[self.moveCount]
    win.blit(self.image, (self.x,self.y)) 
    # The image of the bird on the screen switches between 3 images. The height and width of the bird stay constant.
```

When the user left-clicks, the bird jumps and can 'fly' in between the pipes based on the user's mouseclicks (the y-coordinate of the bird increases each time the mouse is clicked and the y-coordinate of the bird steadily decreases when the user does nothing). How can I now find a way to detect if the bird actually touches one of the pipes, in which case the game will end?

[image: Game preview]

Comment: [`pygame.Rect.colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

Comment: @Rabbid76 how do I make a rect for both the top and bottom parts of the pipe?

Comment: You have to make 3 rectangles. One for the bird, one for the bottom pipe and one for the top pipe. You have to test if the bird hits the top `or` bottom pipe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To check the pipe\bird collision, create a rectangle for the upper\lower pipe in the pipe class then create a method to test for collision:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.bottom = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("pipe.png"), (52,145))
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 52
    self.height = 145
    self.rects = [] # top\bottom pipe

def resize(self): # The height of the pipe will vary randomly
    self.height = random.randint(100,150)
    self.bottom = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("pipe.png"), (52,self.height))
    self.y = 400 - self.height

def draw(self, win):
    if self.x > -52:
        self.x -= 5 # Pipe will move to the left of the screen
    else:
        self.x = 400
        self.resize()
    win.blit(self.bottom, (self.x,self.y))
    self.top = pygame.transform.rotate(self.bottom, 180) # There is a bottom pipe and a top pipe
    win.blit(self.top, (self.x,0)) 
    # save rect list for top\bottom pipe
    self.rects=[
         pygame.rect((self.x,self.y),(self.width,self.height)), # bottom
         pygame.rect((self.x,0),(self.width,self.height))  # top
         ]

def CheckCollide(bird):  # did bird collide with pipe
    birdrect = pygamerect(bird.x. bird.y, bird.width, bird,height)
    for r in self.rects:
       if birdrect.colliderect(r):
           return True  # bird hit pipe
    return False # no collision
```